# JS - Parse \n and other objects to relevant HTML

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I am using the YouTube Data API to retrieve video descriptions and insert them into an HTML document using this:

```
document.getElementById("description").replace("\n", "<br />");
```

The text gets inserted into the element, but the \n's and \"'s are still present. How do I parse them into proper formatting for HTML?

Comment: can you share an example of `\"'s`? and what you want to replace it with?

Comment: I mean that in this way `\"`'s, and I believe it's supposed to just be a `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")`

Example

```
"asd\nasdas".replace(/\n/g, "<br>"); //outputs "asd<br>asdas"
```

**Edit**:

As per the new info given by OP, description carries `\\n` which is a character to indicate carriage return rather than actual carriage return. So the updated answer is as

```
"asd\\nasdas".replace(/\\n/g, "<br>"); //outputs "asd<br>asdas"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It doesn't throw an error message or anything, just nothing happens.

EDIT: I think it's an issue related to the data input rather than the function itself, as it works if I run it on a string like the example in the same situation.

Comment: I said in the post, YouTube API to get the description of a video.

Comment: Can you share the sample description of the video?

Comment: I found the solution, I had to use /\\n/g instead of /\n/g since they are not actual carriage returns and instead are plaintext.

Comment: @Mardan: Please add an example of the input to your question.